# Getting an array item property in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My question revolves around appending items to a dropdownlist based upon choices made on a previous dropdownlist. Here's my code in JS:

```
function propogateProgramListOptions(data) {
    $.post('PostProgramData',
        { clientId: data },
        function(result) {
            var programs = result.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < programs.length; i++) {
                alert(programs[i]);
            }
        });
     }
```

Here's my code in C#:

```
public JsonResult PostProgramData(string[] clientId) {
        string domainUserName = GetDomainUserName();
        ProgramRef[] programsArray = _manager.GetCPRPrograms(domainUserName, clientId);
        List<ProgramRef> programsList = programsArray.ToList();
        return Json(new {data = programsList}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now each ProgramRef has a property of ProgramCode and ProgramName. Usually in C#, you can just iterate through the array and do programsArray[i].ProgramCode etc. But in this case i'm returning it as a Jsonresult. How would i access the ProgramCode and ProgramName properties of the returned item in JS and do result[i].programName?

Comment: why you don't try what you are asking ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad your assumption here seems to be that i did not.

Comment: Try let programs = JSON.parse(result); Then iterate and use .properties on each object.

Comment: @Spartan117 you didn't then showed what you have actually tried, and you didn't showed how your json looks like in result.

Comment: Please execute `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` in the success callback and paste the result here.

Comment: @LarsGyrupBrinkNielsen do you mean JSON.stringify(result)?

Comment: Yes, you are right - `result` or `result.data`.

Comment: Your code shuld work fine. If you want to access a specific property, you need to try it like `programs[i].ProgramCode` inside your for loop. It should work

Comment: @LarsGyrupBrinkNielsen - " [{"ExtensionData":{},"ClientCode":null,"ClientSeqNo":0,"ProgramCode":"CFFP","ProgramName":"CFFP TEST"}"

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.

```
programs[i].ProgramCode
programs[i].ProgramName
```

I didn't think this would work because my IDE was complaining about it being a global variable.